# Good books for MMORPG design?

Tags: mmo, books

What is the recommended reading list for a very experienced s/w developer, with no MMORPG experience, who wants to design an MMORPG?

Comment: Design as in game design, or design as in software architecture?

Comment: As in software architecture

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Richard Bartle, [*Designing Virtual Worlds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Designing_Virtual_Worlds)
- Jessica Mulligan & Bridgette Patrovsky, [*Developing Online Games*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592730000)
- Edward Castronova, [*Synthetic Worlds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226096262)

Hanging around [Terra Nova](http://terranova.blogs.com/terra_nova/) is also probably not a terrible idea.

Comment: This are mostly designing, are there any good books on actually engineering a MMORPG. On topics like, project structure. code structure. techniques to be used by programmers with coding examples?

Comment: @majidarif: You should ask this as a question, not a comment.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/147840/books-on-mmorpg-engineering